# Mysql insert encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to insert Utf-8 string in a cell with `utf8_general_ci` collation

My code:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 ...

 print mb_detect_encoding($name);
 $query = "INSERT INTO items SET name='$name', type='$type'";
 print $query;
 mysql_set_charset('utf8'); // also doesn't help
 $result0 = mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8") or die(mysql_error()); // I've added this line, but it doesn't solve the issue
 $result01 = mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8') or die("set character ".mysql_error()); // still nothing
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

What I see in the html output:

```
UTF-8 INSERT INTO waypoints SET name='ČAS', type='ts'
```

What I see in the database, as `name` in the inserted row:

```
?AS
```

Now my string is utf-8, my table and cell is utf-8 .. why the wrong encoding?

Comment: How do you "see it in the database"? Maybe it is just an encoding problem of your tool.

Comment: How about [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) ?

Comment: phpmyadmin.. anyway I've tried select and print, it is stil ?AS

Comment: You see wrong encoding in html, but what is html encoding, is it UTF-8 ?

Comment: Here's my reference article when it comes to UTF-8 in webapps : http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: yes, the html is also utf-8

Comment: I had some situation like you last month. Everything was set to UTF-8 but there was an error in database. Then I just remove UTF-8 from "CREATE TABLE" quest and for my great surprise it works.

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys, thank you all for help, it looks like I've solved the issue with:

```
 mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $link);
```

right after creating the connection

(especially @Bartdude for the article, which gave me a hint)